# Magento 2 InstallSchema not being executed

Tags: magento2

I've written a basic Magento 2 custom module. The module is able to register with Magento 2 when I run `bin/magento module:enable <module name>`. I've checked the `setup_module` table and the module entry is there and the module is enabled.

I'm having a problem getting my `Setup/InstallSchema.php` to run. Doesn't matter what I do, the schema installer is never executed. I am assuming this is because when I first performed the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command I had a blank `InstallSchema.php`. Disabling and re-enabling the module doesn't do anything. I've checked the database and Magento doesn't appear to use the database to keep track of the module `setup_version`. I've tried finding where on disk Magento tracks the currently installed `setup_version` but so far I've drawn a blank. I know that Magento can call into my module because it is executing the `Setup/InstallData.php` file quite happily.

This is the `Setup/InstallSchema.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace Openxtra\Article\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Installs DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('openxtra_article'))
            ->addColumn(
                'article_id',
                Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                null,
                ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Article ID'
            )
            ->addColumn('url_key', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 100, ['nullable' => true, 'default' => null])
            ->addColumn('title', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, ['nullable' => false], 'Article Title')
            ->addColumn('content', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', [], 'Article Content')
            ->addColumn('is_active', Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'], 'Is Article Active?')
            ->addColumn('created_at', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Article creation time')
            ->addColumn('updated_at', Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, ['nullable' => false], 'Article last updated time')
            ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('article_key_index', ['url_key']), ['url_key'])
            ->setComment('Openxtra Articles');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Anybody any ideas how I can force Magento 2 to execute my `Setup/InstallSchema.php` file?

Comment: Please share your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table setup_module should have the version numbers.

Comment: ,please describe briefly

Comment: Actually this does answer the question. Thanks William, just what I was looking for. I'd missed the schema version in the `setup_module` table. I deleted the row for my table, re-ran the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command and my InstallSchema.php was executed successfully.